# Установка драйвера для postgresql на linux

Tags: postgresql, драйвер, java, linux

Я написал следующую программу на java, читающую из базы данных `postgresql` и записывающую результаты запроса в текстовый файл

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.*;

public class Sample {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException  {
                    int CountComputers;
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
                    "/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/countcomputers.txt");
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String result=br.readLine();
            CountComputers=Integer.parseInt(result);
            input.close();
            fstream.close();
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;    
               String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.8:5432/NexentaSearch";
                String user = "postgres";
                String password = "valter89";
            ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
            try
            {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                        st = con.createStatement();
                        rs = st.executeQuery("select path from tasks order by id");
                while (rs.next()) { paths.add(rs.getString(1)); };
                PrintWriter zzz = null;
                    try
                    {
                            zzz = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/readwaysfromdatabase.txt"));
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Error");
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
                    for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
                {
                    zzz.println("paths[i]=" + paths.get(i) + "\n");
                    }
                    zzz.close();

            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Я скомпилировал эту программу и создал `jar` файл

```
./javac -classpath /folder/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar -d /Samplejavaprogram/classes /Samplejavaprogram/src/Sample.java
./jar -cvf /Samplejavaprogram/Sample.jar -C /Samplejavaprogram/classes/ .
```

а затем запустил эту программу с помощью команды

```
./java -jar /Samplejavaprogram/Sample.jar
```

и в результате получил следующие сообщения

```
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.8:5432/NexentaSearch
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at org.myorg.Sample.main(Sample.java:33)
```

Какой драйвер надо установить и как это сделать в linux (хотелось бы увидеть инструкцию)?

Comment: в Debian/Ubuntu 

aptitude install libpostgresql-jdbc-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC драйвер `postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar` надо включить в конечный `Sample.jar`

**Update**

Просто так включить не получится. Необходимо, чтобы в манифесте JAR'а была строчка типа:

```
Class-Path: lib/<lib1.jar> lib/<lib2.jar>
```

а в каталоге `lib` лежали нужные библиотеки.

Потом собирать jar командой типа:

`jar cvfm <your_jar_file.jar> <manifest_file> <class_files> <libraries>`

Еще раз призываю работайте в IDE: Eclipse или Intellij IDEA - там это все автоматизировано.

Comment: @Barmaley я открыл `WinRar`-ом `Sample.jar` и в корень его содержимого скопировал `postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc4.jar` (я еще обнаружил, что ошибался с версией `postgres` на виртуальной машине (я скомпилировал программу заново с использованием файла `postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc4.jar`, скачанного с http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html по ссылке с надписью 8.4-703 JDBC 4 на этой странице), но несмотря на все это получил тот же результат в итоге.

Comment: @ivan89 покоряйте Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Нужно скачать коннектор и подключить его как библиотеку приложения. 
Скачать можно [отсюда](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)

Comment: Он у него уже есть и входит в CLASSPATH при компиляции - теперь надо чтобы входил в CLASSPATH при выполнении

Comment: @dimka3210 я же скомилировал программу с помощью команды

    ./javac -classpath /folder/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar -d /Samplejavaprogram/classes /Samplejavaprogram/src/Sample.java

с использованием файла `postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar`, скачанного именно с указанной вами страницы. Или вы имели ввиду какой-то другой файл, или же этот, но подразумевали что-то другое под подключением как библиотеки приложения?

Comment: Этот. Извините, просмотрел как-то. А если приложение *.jar открыть как архив, так коннектор имеется? или он рядом должен быть с приложением?

Comment: @dimka3210 Попрошу быть аккуратнее в терминах: обычно под коннектором имеется ввиду немного другое, например Oracle OCI Connector, а здесь это не коннектор, а JDBC драйвер.