# No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://

Tags: драйвер, jdbc, java, postgresql, linux

Согласно ответу @Barmaley, приведенному в вопросе [Установка драйвера для postgresql на linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/214296/java-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-postgresql-%D0%BD%D0%B0-linux), я создал `Sample.jar` того же файла `Sample.java` , приведенного на вышеуказанной странице, с файлом манифеста

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: Sample
Class-Path: /folder/postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc3.jar
```

и с файлом `/folder/postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc3.jar` и запустил jar c помощью команды

```
./java -jar -Djava.library.path=/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/lib /Samplejavaprogram/Sample.jar
```

и в результате получил следующие сообщения

```
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.8:5432/NexentaSearch
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at org.myorg.Sample.main(Sample.java:33)
```

Я запускал файл с хоста с адресом `192.168.1.10`, а на хосте `192.168.1.8` он отработал нормально.

(я изменил программу убрав первые 2 строки:

```
package org.myorg;
```

)

Помогите устранить ошибку.

Answer (score 4):

Похоже проблема в том, что вы не грузите JDBC драйвер.

Посмотрите [инструкцию](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/load.html) по загрузке JDBC драйвера. Магия в `class.forName()`

P.S. Скачайте себе [Intellij IDEA Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) и работайте в нем - жизнь станет намного проще